# Bad Gateway python-telegram-bot with webhook and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, webhooks, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to set up a webhook with python-telegram-bot and Nginx. I am faced with a problem, my bot doesn't get messages from telegram. I also tried to make GET/POST queries from the postman and I always get a "502 Bad Gateway" error. I also launched the netstat to monitor port 5000 where my telegram bot connects but it is always empty. It seems like webhook doesn't launch at all.

My Nginx default.conf file looks like the following:

```
upstream django {
server gunicorn:8000;
}

server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; 
} 

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    server_name example.com www.example.com; 
    ssl_certificate fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location /TELEGRAM_TOKEN {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/TELEGRAM_TOKEN/;
    }

    location /static/ {            
        alias /static/;                   
    }  

    location / {                                
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8000; 
    } 
}
```

And my telegram client code:

```
updater = Updater(api_token)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, custom_command))

jq = updater.job_queue
job_minute = jq.run_repeating(callback_minute, interval=5)

#updater.start_polling()
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0", port=5000, url_path=api_token,
                      webhook_url=f'https://example.com/{api_token}')
updater.idle()
```

I also have Django options for the Nginx server but I've never seen any tutorial or documentation on how to tune the webhook with Django and it can be the reason for my problems.

Have anyone any idea about solving my problem?

Comment: Which ptb version are you using? Please show any error messages in the nginx log. Please also show the output of calling `print(Bot(api_token).get_webhook_info()))`. Is your ssl certificate self-signed? Also it's unclear to me how Django is related to your question, as you're not using django in the python code snippet. please explain.

Comment: When I called get_webhook_info I got the following message: {'last_error_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 19, 8, 56, 58, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'has_custom_certificate': False, 'max_connections': 40, 'ip_address': 'x.x.x.x', 'url': 'https://example.com/TELEGRAM_TOKEN', 'last_error_message': 'Connection refused', 'pending_update_count': 1} I see error but what is it mean? I have python-telegram-bot==13.12 And I create certificate using letsencrypt and check it on digicert and certificate is valid. And I think Django is not related to this question at all.

Comment: I also haven't any errors in nginx log. It's empty.

Answer (score 0):

CallMeStag, your advice to use the following code helped me solve the issue:

`print(Bot(api_token).get_webhook_info()))`

I had 2 problems with the Nginx config file

**First: ssl on**

It gave me an error connection refused and I deleted it

**Second**

I changed this

```
    location /TELEGRAM_TOKEN {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/TELEGRAM_TOKEN/;
    }
```

to this

```
    location /TELEGRAM_TOKEN {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:5000/TELEGRAM_TOKEN/;
    }
```

and the webhook is now working.

Thank you.